# Can I get Mehrunes' Razor after sparing Silus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I saved Silus now I want the razor :P Because my character turned bad. I have PC so console commands would be cool :p

Comment: Ok, so this is a pain. But I put all my stuff in a chest and just had some light armour and a dagger. But when I come back to it. All the deadric stuff and the artifacts are gone :I

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no way to go back on your decision to spare Silus and get the Razor instead. If you're playing on PC, however, you can just give yourself the Razor with the console command `player.additem 000240d2 1`. Killing Silus before or after doing so is optional.

Comment: Ummm, ok :p But its like the 'Dawnbreaker Scabbard' thing. It really needs to be done but anyone who wants it ain't a modder :I

Comment: killing Silus is optional but you need to kill him if you want to get the achievement for obtaining all the artifacts, additem doesn't work for that.

Comment: Ok, I already had the achievments and this was my 3rd playthough where I was a good dude, got bored of that and turned into an assasin :P